# Can't execute mulitple pom.xml files in quiet mode

Tags: maven

I am trying to run multiple pom.xml files from the parent pom.xml file using -quiet command from the command line. But the command is working only for the parent pom.xml file and not the other pom.xml files which it is calling. I tried to find out to add some changes in the pom.xml files to make them run in -quiet mode but I there is only one way I can see through command line.

Below is the directory structure

Parentdir

--- Pom.xml

dir2

--- pom.xml

dir3

--- pom.xml

dir4

--- pom.xml

I want to trigger pom.xml of the Parentdir from the Parentdir directory in the quiet mode so that all the pom.xml files should run in a quiet mode.

The command I used is `mvn -q clean install`

This command only executes pom.xml of the Parentdir and not the other pom.xml files in quiet mode.

Can I get some help on this please?

Comment: This question is hard to follow. What is your directory structure? What Maven commands are you using? What is the command line output? Please add this information to the question by _editing_ it.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you please check and advice?

Comment: You defined the modules in the parent POM correctly?

Comment: I don't know what is the module for quite mode exactly... If we there is any then please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the below line from info to error in maven's simplelogger.properties I got want I wanted.

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info
```

to

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=error
```